# WinRT XAML - how to fix higlight issues?

Tags: winrt-xaml

When I'm testing my app on a mouse-driven device, I'm seeing a couple of odd highlight issues that I would like to try and resolve.

The first occurs when I call up the app bar, hover the mouse over a button (at which point the button goes grey) and then press Escape to dismiss the app bar. If I then call up the app bar again, the button has stayed grey, even if the mouse isn't over it, and remains in that state until I move the mouse over it and then away again.

[image: Highlighted button]

I can't immediately see a property of the button that I can reset to clear that state when the app bar gets dismissed.

The other oddity I'm seeing is that sometimes the first item in the list on the page will get a box drawn around it:

[image: List item with box around it]

This seems to happen when the app bar is being dismissed. I'm guessing that this is because the item is in a particular state that causes the box to appear but I'm not sure what state or how to clear it. The box does not appear during normal use of my app.

Thanks for any clarification or solutions you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple way to workaround this issue. In the code for Clicked/Tapped set `Visibility` of the button:

```
CreateNewDatabase.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
CreateNewDatabase.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

It will reset button state to Normal.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

So, the issue is that the `VisualState` for the `Button` is being set to `PointedOver`, and then not being unset (because your mouse isn't leaving the bounds of the control and therefore triggering a `PointerExited` event). What this means is that you'll have to manually set the `VisualState` of the `Button` if you want it to change in this manner. You could do it on `AppBar`'s `Closed` event. Basically, do a recursive check of all `Children` of the `Content` property of the `AppBar` using the `VisualTreeHelper`. Check to see if the `Child` is a `Button`. If it is, set its `VisualState` using `VisualStateManager.GoToState()`.

Comment: Thank you - this is a big help. However (and I may be doing something wrong), it doesn't seem to be working. I'm calling `VisualStateManager.GoToState(control, "Normal", true);` but the visual state seems to be sticking still. I'm not sure if "Normal" is the correct state to be changing to or if I should be using a different one?

Answer (score 0):

I've also figured out what was causing the black box around the button - it is to indicate that the button has Focus.

The rather strange thing is that I'm not really sure why that specific button is getting focus or how a user is supposed to give focus to a button without it just randomly happening so, until I figure that out, I've decided to comment out the Focus state support from the Visual Manager XAML used in the default GridView item style.